# I want to remove double quotes from a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, paypal

```
var aProd = "{'name':'Product One','description':'Description Product One','unit_amount':{'currency_code':'USD','value':'247','sku':'h545'},'quantity':'1'}";


var item = new Array(aProd);
  console.log(item);
```

result this

```
[
    "{'name':'Product One','description':'Description Product One','unit_amount':{'currency_code':'USD','value':'247','sku':'h545'},'quantity':'1'}"
]
```

How remove double quotes?

to this

```
[
    {'name':'Product One','description':'Description Product One','unit_amount':{'currency_code':'USD','value':'247','sku':'h545'},'quantity':'1'}
]
```

already tried

var item = new Array(String(ci).replace(/"/g, ""));

or

var item = ci.toString().replace(/"/g, "");

but I can't remove double quotes

Comment: Do you want to get string array or object array?

Comment: object to use paypal cart smart button item

Comment: Then you should JSON pasrse

Comment: where does this string come from? it looks almost like JSON, but not exactly. Like, what generated this almost-JSON with the wrong type of quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.parse` (after converting all single quotes to double quotes):

```js
let aProd = "{'name':'Product One','description':'Description Product One','unit_amount':{'currency_code':'USD','value':'247','sku':'h545'},'quantity':'1'}";
let res = [JSON.parse(aProd.replaceAll("'", '"'))];
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create an array with that data as its first object. Now, the data isn't valid JSON so you need to replace all the single quotes with double quotes first, parse it, and then wrap it in `[]` braces.

```js
const aProd = "{'name':'Product One','description':'Description Product One','unit_amount':{'currency_code':'USD','value':'247','sku':'h545'},'quantity':'1'}";

// Replace the single quotes with double quotes
const json = aProd.replaceAll("'", '"');

// Parse the now-valid JSON, and place it in an array
const arr = [JSON.parse(json)];

// Here's your new data structure
console.log(arr);

// And here, and an example, we log the value
// of `name` from the object which is the
// first `[0]` element of the array
console.log(arr[0].name);
```